# Erro no final da instalação do Symfony

Tags: php, symfony-2, symfony

Estou querendo aprender `Symfony` e dai fiz a instalação como eles falam no site:

```
composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition meuprojeto/ '~2.5'
```

Até ai fez a instalação, no final eu não quis instalar a demo `Acme` e fiz as configurações, entrei na pasta do projeto, rodei o comando:

```
php app/check.php
```

E fica tudo OK, quando rodei o comando:

```
php app/console server:run
```

Abri no meu navegador o endereço que ele passou:

```
 http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

Mas dá os erros:

> Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found. 2/2
>   NotFoundHttpException: No route found for "GET /" 1/2
>   ResourceNotFoundException:

Já tentei acessar:

```
127.0.0.1:8000/app_dev.php
```

Também não deu, alguém sabe como posso ter ter um `hello world`?

Comment: Sua versão do php é 5.4+ ? Possui apache instalado?

Comment: Versão do php 5.5.* e apache ok

Answer (score 2):

Esse erro acontece porque você, de fato, não definiu nenhuma rota mapeada para `/`. Se você tivesse instalado o `AcmeDemoBundle` teria uma rota inicial para explorar, que seria a `/hello/{name}`.

O próximo passo agora é criar um *bundle* dentro da sua aplicação Symfony com o comando `app/console generate:bundle`. Dentro desse bundle haverá um arquivo `Resources/config/routing.yml` no qual você define as rotas da sua aplicação, que serão mapeadas para actions em seus controllers e que, por fim, gerarão respostas HTML válidas para suas requisições.

Answer (score 0):

Depois de algumas pesquisas a mais, vi que esse erro estava dando por causa que não tinha nada configurado no `routing.yml` e dai o que fiz foi criar uma página de exemplo `php app/console generate:bundle --namespace=Acme/DemoBundle --format=yml` seguindo esse link http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/page_creation.html .
Também adicionei no composer.json , na parte do `extra` o seguinte

```
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "symfony-assets-install": "symlink", // <- essa linha foi adicionada
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    },
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "2.5-dev"
    }
}
```

fiz isso pois depois de criar uma página demo começou a dar erro com os assets.

Espero que possa ajudar para futuras consultas.

Answer (score 0):

Oii amigo, o Hello World vem implementado no AcmeBundle. O problema do "No route found" é porque não existe a rota que você pretende acessar. Vou te ensinar os passos para criar um novo bundle e criar uma rota para ele.

Rode no console o comando:

```
php bin/console generate:bundle
```

Após, ele irá fazer umas perguntas sobre o nome do bundle, utilize o annotation. Depois de gerar o bundle, ele vai ter dentro do Bundle um `DefaultController`. E o método `indexAction` que é gerado automático terá a rota `@Route("/")`, isso significa que é a rota raíz do seu servidor.

```
/** 
 * @Route("/")
 * @Method("GET")
 */
public function indexAction() {

}
```

O HTML se encontrará na pasta `Resources/views` dentro do Bundle. Os arquivos estarão dentro da pasta com o mesmo nome do Bundle.

Se você rodar o servidor do Symfony `php bin/console server:run`, você poderá acessar o seu projeto através do endereço `http://localhost:8000/` e como está na rota raíz, ele irá abrir o seu `indexAction`.

Se a rota for:

```
/** 
 * @Route("/teste")
 * @Method("GET")
 */
public function indexAction() {

}
```

O endereço será `http://localhost:8000/teste`. Espero ter ajudado!